# How to increase queries per minute per user limit?

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-search, google-contacts-api, google-custom-search, google-search-api

I have 100 queries per minute per user. But it's not enough for my project. How can I increase this limit? I already have billing account. I sent a request form to Google. But they increased only queries per day 1,000 to 30,000. Need per minute per user limit.

[my-limits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWO8g.png)

Comment: I don't know if this is an option for you, but have you already reviewed your code that is making the requests? Are you making 1+N requests? If so, consider batching requests together in a single request, reducing the amount of requests made.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the quotaUser parameter https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage#limiting_requests_per_user